# Unable to sign-in into Google Play Store after logging out

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, connection-issues

I downloaded Freedom app, but I didn't find it interesting, so I uninstalled it completely. After a while I tried opening my Google Play Store, but it didn't open and shows: "No connection - retry".

So I logged myself out of Google to see if the problem is resolved or not.
But unfortunately, it didn't, and now, I am not able to log into my Google account, and ultimately, unable to use Google Play Store. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Freedom again. Open Freedom, tap the three dots on the top-right corner and tap **Stop** as in the picture shown above.

[image: A]

See [my answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/183500/205764).

Answer (score -1):

Remove your Google account from phone.
To do this, go to Settings -> Accounts. Now removal process depends on device and OS version so you will have to find how to remove it on your own.

Now go to Settings -> Apps -> Google Play services -> Delete Data/Clear Cache.
Do the same procedure for Google Play Store app.

Reboot device and try to add account again.