# How to fix YouTube and and GooglePlay store problems?

Tags: google-play-store, google

can anybody help me?  A couple of days ago I went to YouTube and a message popped up saying "Check your connection and try again" same thing happened with the play store.  I saw that my WiFi was perfect.  I rebooted my device and re-connected to my wifi but it's still the same.  The other devices on the same wifi was working perfectly.  And the problem is also same with my Data connection.  So my wifi and data connection,  none of them are working. Please somebody help me.

Thanks, Apon.

Comment: Did you use some VPN or freedom like apps recently?

Comment: No.  I watched  youtube and let my device charge for a while.  After 3 hours I came back and that happened. And what do u mean mean by freedom like apps? @Vivek Ji

Comment: There is a freedom app that does something with hosts file, and that screws play store connectivity.

Comment: That's a bummer. I used to have that app. It actually hacked offline games.  I have deleted it.  Now what should I do?  @Vivek Ji

Comment: Very well..... http://android.stackexchange.com/q/120467/131341 Try answers from these posts. They must get you out of situation.

Comment: @AponRoy Congrats! You are now tethered to freedom! In personal experience, you can fix this by- I'm not kidding- Installing freedom again. Got me out of many an issue. Also, +1 For a good first question.